# Character jumping while moving right and left AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, game-physics

I am making a platform game where the main character moves around and jumps.

I want the character to jump left and right separately. Maybe using two keys at the same time And land on top of the floor.  My characters movie clip symbol is `Naruto` and my floor movie clip symbol is `floor`.

My project file can be found here: [Naruto Game](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8d5opy49fuqmup5/naruto.fla)

In order to do this I have a main movie-clip with all the other movie-clips inside such as *"jump right"* and *"jump left"*.

What I'm having a problem with, is when **THE USER IS MOVING RIGHT I WANT THE CHARACTER TO FACE RIGHT WHEN JUMPING** (and the same with the left).

[image: My stage]

```
 import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
 import flash.ui.Keyboard;
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.display.Stage;

 naruto.gotoAndStop("stance");
 var rightPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
 var leftPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
 var upPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
 var downPressed: Boolean = new Boolean(false);
 var narutoSpeed: Number = 10;
 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
 stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);


 function keyDownHandler(keyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = true;
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftPressed = true;
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upPressed = true;
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed = true;
    }

 }

 function keyUpHandler(keyEvent: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = false;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("standright")
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftPressed = false;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("standleft")
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upPressed = false;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("stance")
    } else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed = false;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("stance")
    }

 }

 function gameLoop(loopEvent: Event): void {
    if (rightPressed) {
        naruto.x += narutoSpeed;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("right");


    } else if (leftPressed) {
        naruto.x -= narutoSpeed;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("left");

    } else if (upPressed) {

        naruto.gotoAndStop("jumpright");

    }

 }
```

**I owe so much to the person that can solve this I have been trying to solve this for a week! Thank you  very much!**

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you're trying to use.  While a link to your project can be helpful, not everyone is comfortable download files from strangers and everything needed to solve your question should be included in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, sir, i will add my code.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding what the problem is.  You want two keys to have to be pressed for left/right walking and you don't know how to handle simultaneous keystrokes?  Or are you getting some kind of error or unexpected result?

Comment: No, i want the character to face right when jumping if necessary and face left when jumping when necessary.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need change your `else` statements into additional`if` statements (so instead of being one or the other, you can potentially get both actions - jump & right).

Here is a code example:

```
function gameLoop(loopEvent: Event): void {
    //If the right key is pressed, and the left key is NOT pressed.
    if (rightPressed && !leftPressed) {
        naruto.x += narutoSpeed;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("right");
    }

    if(leftPressed && !rightPressed) {
        naruto.x -= narutoSpeed;
        naruto.gotoAndStop("left");
    }

    if (upPressed) {
        //if up is pressed, and right is pressed
        if(rightPressed && !leftPressed) naruto.gotoAndStop("jumpright");
        if(leftPressed && !rightPressed) naruto.gotoAndStop("jumpleft");
    }

    if(leftPressed && rightPressed && !upPressed){
        naruto.gotoAndStop("stance");  //if left & right are pressed, they negate each other and you play stance
    }
}
```

With this code, if the right key is pressed, `naruto` will move right.  If up is also pressed, then in addition to moving right, it will switch from the *right* state to the *jumpright* state.

Comment: Can you please one up my question

Comment: Can you please one up my question